# Behavior of QTreeView when inserting column at index 0

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, qtreeview

I'm trying to understand a strange (to my understanding) behavior when trying to insert a column in a treeview at index 0.

While I understand that this is not a suggested course of action, the result still puzzles me.

If I add a child to an item that is not in the first column, it is obviously not shown, since only children of the root index in first column are expanded; but it seems that when the new column is inserted, the existing children of the previous first column are "inherited" by the new item.

```
class TreeTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        insertColBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('insert column')
        layout.addWidget(insertColBtn)
        insertColBtn.clicked.connect(self.insertColumn)

        insertColAfterBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('insert child and insert column')
        layout.addWidget(insertColAfterBtn)
        insertColAfterBtn.clicked.connect(self.insertColumnAfter)

        removeColBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('remove column')
        layout.addWidget(removeColBtn)
        removeColBtn.clicked.connect(self.removeColumn)

        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.parent1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('parent 1')
        self.parent2 = QtGui.QStandardItem('parent 2')
        self.model.appendRow([self.parent1, self.parent2])
        self.child = QtGui.QStandardItem('child of parent 1')
        self.parent1.appendRow(self.child)
        self.parent2.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem('child of parent 2'))
        self.tree.expandAll()
        self.tree.header().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

    def insertColumn(self):
        newParent = QtGui.QStandardItem('new parent')
        self.model.insertColumn(0, [newParent])
        newChild = QtGui.QStandardItem('new column child')
        self.parent1.appendRow(newChild)

    def insertColumnAfter(self):
        newParent = QtGui.QStandardItem('new parent')
        newChild = QtGui.QStandardItem('new column child')
        self.parent1.appendRow(newChild)
        self.model.insertColumn(0, [newParent])

    def removeColumn(self):
        self.model.removeColumn(0)
```

This is the what appears at the beginning (the "child of parent 2" is obviously hidden):

[image: first shown, child item of the first column is visible, child of second is not]

Then I insert a new first column, *then* I add a child to the previous parent (which is now on the second column); as you can see, the previous child is now apparently become a child of the new item, while the new child item is not visible:

[image: column inserted, child of the previous parent is "inherited"]

Finally, I try to remove the first column, and the previously added child is now visible:

[image: first column removed, previously added child is now visible]

Strangely enough, if a new child item of the previous first column is added *before* inserting the new column (`insertColumnAfter()`), it works "as expected", probably due to the delay item views usually have before laying out the items after a model change:

[image: add a child item, then insert a new column]

Again, I realize this is not the "standard" way to deal with a tree model.
Still, I'd like to understand what's going on here, whether it's an expected behavior (probably by design, even if not perfect) or some kind of bug.

I've been able to reproduce this behavior with PyQt up to 5.12.4, I can't test with newer versions.

Comment: It looks like a bug. It would be good to test it in C++ and verify that the error is from Qt and not from binding (PyQt5/PySide2). The error appears in the bindings so it seems to me a Qt error. I have tested it in Qt 5.14.1 on Linux.

Comment: Also you cannot collapse the items

Comment: @eyllanesc right, I didn't notice the collapse problem. I also believe it might be a Qt error, I'm writing to the PyQt mailing list anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I looked at this and my impression is that you are implementing something incorrectly. I say this because when you add a new column you are dramatically changing your Item Model without compensating for that. For instance add a second row initially then do your add column and you can see what I mean. So I am not convinced this is a bug as much as a faulty implementation which I can understand having had to deal with the Item Model class myself.

Comment: @DennisJensen As I specified in the post, I'm well aware that this is not the normal way to deal with a tree model structure, but that's not the point: it shouldn't behave like this at all.